# Amazon EC2 Cron job stops after some hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, amazon-ec2, cron, capistrano, whenever

I am using [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to schedule cron job every 15 minutes in my rails 3.2 application and [capistrano gem](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) to deploy it on amazon EC2 instance.

The issue is:

Whenever I deploy with `cap deploy`, the cron job works fine(every 15minutes).
But it stops after some variable hours. The next day, when I see cron log, the cron job had already stopped running.
I deploy the code again and the cron job starts working again and stops after some hours.

Please help.

Comment: any chance you could share your schedule code and/or the corresponding crontab command generated

Comment: I found the problem, Actually I have 2 applications on amazon server, whenever I deploy the another application(the one without scheduler), crontab becomes empty, cause capistrano updates crontab each time the code is deployed.